# Using enum to go around variable array size

Tags: c, enums

I am using enum to go around the variable array size. The main catch here is a prior integer value will mention which enum value to use. Example 1,  can be indexed. But I do not understand the  MyEnumArray[] = {A, B, C, D} as this was trial and error - but [why I can declare and array here and index it whereas I cannot do the same with typedef and how can I do same thing with typedef Example 3 or how can the same result can be reached].

```
//EXAMPLE 1 - WORKS No typedef
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum Letter
{
    A = 1,
    B,
    C,
    D
} MyEnumArray[] = {A, B, C, D}; 

//Looked up other examples and coded and this works. 
//But why is MyEnumArray declared here as an array and same values and I can index it to make it work. 
//It does not work with typedef Example 3 below and so I had to remove MyEnumArray. 

void printOut(int variableArraySize);
int main()
{
    int arrayVariableSize = 3;
    enum Letter getArraySize = MyEnumArray[arrayVariableSize];
    printOut(getArraySize);

    return 0;
}

void printOut(int variableArraySize)
{
    printf("Number of Array Inputs: %d\n", variableArraySize);
    int xVarryingArray[variableArraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < variableArraySize; i++)
    {
        xVarryingArray[i] = i * i * 10;
        printf("xVarryingArray[%d] = %d\n", i, xVarryingArray[i]);
    }
}
//Output 
Number of Array Inputs: 4
xVarryingArray[0] = 0 
xVarryingArray[1] = 10
xVarryingArray[2] = 40
xVarryingArray[3] = 90
```

```
//EXAMPLE 2 - With typedef does work but, the enum value is hard-coded. 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum Letter
{
    A = 1,
    B,
    C,
    D
} Letter;
void printOut(int variableArraySize);
int main()
{
    int arrayVariableSize = 3;
    enum Letter getArraySize = D; //I want to somehow get this value from arrayVariableSize
    printOut(getArraySize);

    return 0;
}

void printOut(int variableArraySize)
{
    printf("Number of Array Inputs: %d\n", variableArraySize);
    int xVarryingArray[variableArraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < variableArraySize; i++)
    {
        xVarryingArray[i] = i * i * 10;
        printf("xVarryingArray[%d] = %d\n", i, xVarryingArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Example 3: Want to make this version work - it does not compile
This version with typdef does not work. And I want to set the enum value from a prior integer variable value. How can this be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum Letter
{
    A = 1,
    B,
    C,
    D
} MyEnumArray[] = {A, B, C, D};
void printOut(int variableArraySize);
int main()
{
    int arrayVariableSize = 3;
    enum Letter getArraySize = MyEnumArray[arrayVariableSize]; //I want to somehow get this value from arrayVariableSize
    printOut(getArraySize);

    return 0;
}

void printOut(int variableArraySize)
{
    printf("Number of Array Inputs: %d\n", variableArraySize);
    int xVarryingArray[variableArraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < variableArraySize; i++)
    {
        xVarryingArray[i] = i * i * 10;
        printf("xVarryingArray[%d] = %d\n", i, xVarryingArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't define a variable and a type with `typedef` — you can only define (an alias for) a type.  In Example 1, you've not specified a storage class; in Example 3, you have — syntactically, `typedef` is a storage class.  But it is a storage class that gives a name to a type.  And you can't provide an initializer when you're defining a type.

Comment: You have `typedef enum Letter { A = 1, B, C, D } MyEnumArray[] = {A, B, C, D};` in Example 3.  You would need to do something like `typedef enum Letter { A = 1, B, C, D } Letter; Letter MyEnumArray[] = {A, B, C, D};`.  This defines a type `Letter` as an alias for the type `enum Letter`, and then defines an array initialized with the values as in Example 1.

Comment: I'm not convinced that Example 2 adds anything except volume to the question.

Comment: You can just write `enum Letter getArraySize = arrayVariableSize;`. Enums can convert back and forth with integer types.